# Python: Object has no attribute 'append' Error

Tags: python, django, parsing

In my dashboard function I have a profile. Profiles have tags. What i'm trying to do is throw each tag that went through the parser into a list. And then that list to the template:

```
import feedparser
rss_result = []
tags = profile.tags.all()
for tag in tags:
    rss = feedparser.parse(tag.tag_rss) #tag.tag_rss is a url string  
    rss.append(rss_result) 
context['tag_rss'] = rss_result
```

It's throwing this error: `Exception Value: object has no attribute 'append`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant to do `rss_result.append(rss)`. You have it backwards.

Also, you could write it in fewer lines with a list comprehension. Entirely up to you, though.

```
import feedparser
tags = profile.tags.all()
context['tag_rss'] = [feedparser.parse(tag.tag_rss) for tag in tags]
# if you don't need to re-use rss_result, this should work okay
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

`rss.append(rss_result)`

to

`rss_result.append(rss)`

You want to append the item `rss` to the list, which is `rss_result`.

When you have an error like this it's helpful to try and parse out what the error is actually telling you:

> Exception Value: object has no attribute 'append'

There seems to be a problem here when trying to call the attribute, append, so if you look back in your code you can see the only place you're trying to append something, is when you have `rss.append(rss_result)`. In this case you can easily see that it's trying to call append on `rss`, and by looking at your code you can see that `rss` is the container for the `feedparser` output, and you don't want to append anything to that, you want that object to be appended to something else.

In this case you want to take your list, `rss_result`, and `append` the `rss` variable to the end of this empty list. hence: `rss_result.append(rss)`

Answer (score 0):

your mixed up this line: rss.append(rss_result) 
should be rss_result.append(rss)